# Fabric plugin is not showing an option to apply changes in code for crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I  created a new account of fabric and trying to add crashlytics using plugin https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-crashlytics-for-android-by-fabric-tutorial/

It has been added in my android studio but it does not show this screen https://www.numetriclabz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/crashlytics-code.png  where I can apply changes in my code.

It asks me to make the changes to your code but it is not making changes itself which it should do.

[image]

On clicking on next button then it navigates on below screen

[image]

Does anyone know why it is acting weird ?

Comment: Found any solutions?>

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here, based on your two screenshots, it looks like the code has changed. If it hasn't still, then you can copy the code out of the plugin and manually place it in.

Comment: It's unclear without looking at the logs, but likely we couldn't detect your project's structure to be confident we wouldn't cause issues if we did it automatically. The fallback in that case is to present the code to you instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "project structure" I think your tool has some issue with latest android studio 3.0 canary 6

Comment: The layout and structure of your project in Android Studio. We currently don't test against Canary builds, but I'll test on a more stable release.